# How can I know which line in csv error when I LOAD INFILE?

Tags: php, mysql

It's simple code

```
$loadsql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$target_path'
    INTO TABLE `test`
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
    IGNORE 1 LINES";
    $result = mysql_query($loadsql);
```

Code is working well. But I just curious How can I know if there's one line error in csv , What line it is ?

Comment: What SQL error do you get in that circumstance?

Comment: I didn't get any error. So I don't know what should it be. 
If some data in csv doesn't match with data type, What error should I get ?? 
I try it on sql and it shows #1054 - Unknown column '....' in 'field list' 
ps.I directly insert into db.

Comment: Well if the LOAD DATA INFILE doesn't give you a line number, then you're probably limited to searching for it manually

Comment: @crazyoxygen I've played around with this. I wasn't able to produce an error. Even a dup key error will silently ignored. (using the command-line client) That's really unsatisfying

Comment: Oh I just try LOAD INFILE with bad csv.SQL will skip error line and do next line without error show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

> With LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE, **data-interpretation and duplicate-key
>   errors become warnings** and the operation continues because the server
>   has no way to stop transmission of the file in the middle of the
>   operation. For duplicate-key errors, this is the same as if IGNORE is
>   specified. IGNORE is explained further later in this section.

Are you certain that the was no *warning* reported? To view them try to use [`SHOW WARNINGS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-warnings.html) in your mysql console.

PS/Warning are attached to a *session* -- you could only *show* them from the session whom you *load* the data file.

PS2/ Just like in [c](/questions/tagged/c), with MySQL *warnings* differs from *errors* as they do not stop the current operations. But they usually indicate that something went wrong and they should be investigated. As for the specific case of `LOAD DATA INFILE`, as the documentation clearly state it, the choice to report warnings instead of errors was only dictated by the fact that there is no (elegant) way for the server to stop the file transfer once it has started.